# Import at the top of the file with gi

Tags: python, python-import, pep8

For libnotify I use the following code

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import Notify
```

Then `flake8` complains that:

```
E402 module level import not at top of file
```

On the other hand, one has to specify the version when using gi: http://mednis.info/use-girequire_versiongtk-30-before-import.html

What should I do? Ignore the linter's messages or remove the `gi.require_version` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `# noqa: E402` at the top of the file to ignore just this error in this file.

Sometimes, imports that aren't at the top of the file are necessary. For example, to avoid a circular import, to avoid the overheard of initializing a module until a certain function is called, or for configuration as is the case here. Imports can have significant side-effects, so in edge-cases like this is perfectly acceptable to have an import further down from the top.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for  me. If I put `# noqa: E402 on every import line it works, but that is unwieldy`